# How to modify list from InfoPath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am trying to modify a list made in **Sharepoint Designer 2013** so when I go to the Design Form option in InfoPath I get the following error:

```
InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the Sharepoint list
```

Inside the box I have the following details

```
Form customization is not supported for this SharePoint list.
```

Additional to Sharepoint Designer 2013 I found this Sharepoint Online configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see "InfoPath does not support customizing the form used for this list", which means that this list type is not supported, such as **calendars** or **document libraries**.

As a workaround, we suggest you use PowerApps to customize list form in SharePoint online.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to what Julie pointed out - In case it is a Form library you can click on Library settings > Advanced Settings >(Edit Template)

This should open the current form in infopath